# How can I change the value of 'Draw Halo' inside Point Light - Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, light

I can't seem to find a Draw Halo property in the intellisense. Is there a way to set its value programmatically? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**:

```
public Component AddComponent(string className);
```

is now deprecated and removed so it can no longer be used to do this. Take a look at the extension method I made, called `AddComponentExt` that can be used to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42357931/3785314).

The answer is to use: `gameObject.AddComponentExt("Halo");`

---

**OLD ANSWER**:

Even though this has been answered, I think that other people that will run into this will this useful.

In addition to [*rutter's*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40756537/3785314) answer,

*The `Halo` class cannot be accessed directly like other components*.

There are two overloads for the `GetComponent` function:

```
public Component GetComponent(Type type);
public Component GetComponent(string type);
```

And two overloads for the `AddComponent` function:

```
public Component AddComponent(Type componentType);
public Component AddComponent(string className);
```

You have to use `GetComponent` and `AddComponent` with the `string` parameter not the one with the `Type` parameter.

`GetComponent("Halo");` and `AddComponent("Halo");` **will** compile.

`GetComponent<Halo>();` and `AddComponent<Halo>();` will **NOT** compile.

In addition, you need to use reflection to toggle `Halo` on and off by enabling/disabling it.

Extension method  that toggles Halo on/off with reflection:

```
public static class ExtensionMethod
{
    public static void drawHalo(this Light light, bool value)
    {
        //Get Halo Component
        object halo = light.GetComponent("Halo");
        //Get Enable Halo property
        var haloInfo = halo.GetType().GetProperty("enabled");
        //Enable/Disable Halo
        haloInfo.SetValue(halo, value, null);
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
Light light = GameObject.Find("Point light").GetComponent<Light>();
light.drawHalo(true); //Extension function. pass true or false
```

**Note**:

Make sure to attach `Halo` to the `Light` before using this function.
Select your light, then go to *Component* -> *Effects* -> *Halo*. You can also do it from script with `yourLight.AddComponent("Halo");`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using this now. I almost gave up on this.

Comment: Glad you found it to be useful.

Answer (score 1):

`Halo` is a separate component.

To add a halo to a light: `AddComponent<Halo>()`

To access the halo attached to a light: `GetComponent<Halo>()`

The "Draw Halo" checkbox in the inspector is a bit of a red herring -- it creates a `Halo` component which is then hidden from the hierarchy view, which is boneheaded but it's preserved from older versions of Unity.

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful :)