# Unity: How to dynamically attach an unknown script to a GameObject (custom editor)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently making a system for the Unity Editor (custom inspector and custom windows) that will automate and make things easier for the artists working on the game we're making, but I've hit a brick wall.

I'm trying to find a way to dynamically add, through an editor Textfield input and a GUI button, an unknown script to a gameobject in the scene.
The artist/programmer will type the name of the script in the textfield and it will search and add to a gameobject, but I don't know how to proceed with this, specially since some functions of `gameObject.AddComponent()` are deprecated as of Unity 5.3

Here's what I tried to do:

```
public string scriptname;
GameObject obj = null;
scriptname = EditorGUILayout.TextField("Script name:", scriptname, GUILayout.MaxHeight(25));
if (GUILayout.Button("Attach script"))
{
    //search for the script to check if it exists, using DirectoryInfo
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(Application.dataPath);
    FileInfo[] info = dir.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    foreach (FileInfo f in info) // cycles through all the files
    {
        if(f.Name == scriptname)
        {
            //attaches to the gameobject (NOT WORKING)
            System.Type MyScriptType = System.Type.GetType(scriptname + ",Assembly-CSharp"); 
            obj.AddComponent(MyScriptType);
        }
    }
}
```

(Of course, this is a summed up version, I copied the relevant lines from different parts of the script).

But it doesn't work.
Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly is not working? Finding the script, attaching it to the gameobject or both? What happens when you execute your code?

Comment: Attaching to the gameobject is the problem here, the two lines inside the GUILayout.Button. To find I'm using DirectoryInfo (actually to check if it exists). I'll add the search system I'm using to the code above as well.

Comment: To find if the type exists you can just do `assembly.GetTypes().Any(t => t.Name == scriptname);`

Comment: Do you get any output in the console? Such as warnings or errors?

Comment: @NathanDanzmann Did you try the solution I added?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After extensive experiment I was able get this. This covers *all* the Unity components too. Just made it an extension method to make life easier.

```
public static class ExtensionMethod
{
    public static Component AddComponentExt(this GameObject obj, string scriptName)
    {
        Component cmpnt = null;


        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            //If call is null, make another call
            cmpnt = _AddComponentExt(obj, scriptName, i);

            //Exit if we are successful
            if (cmpnt != null)
            {
                break;
            }
        }


        //If still null then let user know an exception
        if (cmpnt == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Failed to Add Component");
            return null;
        }
        return cmpnt;
    }

    private static Component _AddComponentExt(GameObject obj, string className, int trials)
    {
        //Any script created by user(you)
        const string userMadeScript = "Assembly-CSharp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null";
        //Any script/component that comes with Unity such as "Rigidbody"
        const string builtInScript = "UnityEngine, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null";

        //Any script/component that comes with Unity such as "Image"
        const string builtInScriptUI = "UnityEngine.UI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null";

        //Any script/component that comes with Unity such as "Networking"
        const string builtInScriptNetwork = "UnityEngine.Networking, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null";

        //Any script/component that comes with Unity such as "AnalyticsTracker"
        const string builtInScriptAnalytics = "UnityEngine.Analytics, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null";

        //Any script/component that comes with Unity such as "AnalyticsTracker"
        const string builtInScriptHoloLens = "UnityEngine.HoloLens, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null";

        Assembly asm = null;

        try
        {
            //Decide if to get user script or built-in component
            switch (trials)
            {
                case 0:

                    asm = Assembly.Load(userMadeScript);
                    break;

                case 1:
                    //Get UnityEngine.Component Typical component format
                    className = "UnityEngine." + className;
                    asm = Assembly.Load(builtInScript);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    //Get UnityEngine.Component UI format
                    className = "UnityEngine.UI." + className;
                    asm = Assembly.Load(builtInScriptUI);
                    break;

                case 3:
                    //Get UnityEngine.Component Video format
                    className = "UnityEngine.Video." + className;
                    asm = Assembly.Load(builtInScript);
                    break;

                case 4:
                    //Get UnityEngine.Component Networking format
                    className = "UnityEngine.Networking." + className;
                    asm = Assembly.Load(builtInScriptNetwork);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    //Get UnityEngine.Component Analytics format
                    className = "UnityEngine.Analytics." + className;
                    asm = Assembly.Load(builtInScriptAnalytics);
                    break;

                case 6:
                    //Get UnityEngine.Component EventSystems format
                    className = "UnityEngine.EventSystems." + className;
                    asm = Assembly.Load(builtInScriptUI);
                    break;

                case 7:
                    //Get UnityEngine.Component Audio format
                    className = "UnityEngine.Audio." + className;
                    asm = Assembly.Load(builtInScriptHoloLens);
                    break;

                case 8:
                    //Get UnityEngine.Component SpatialMapping format
                    className = "UnityEngine.VR.WSA." + className;
                    asm = Assembly.Load(builtInScriptHoloLens);
                    break;

                case 9:
                    //Get UnityEngine.Component AI format
                    className = "UnityEngine.AI." + className;
                    asm = Assembly.Load(builtInScript);
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Debug.Log("Failed to Load Assembly" + e.Message);
        }

        //Return if Assembly is null
        if (asm == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        //Get type then return if it is null
        Type type = asm.GetType(className);
        if (type == null)
            return null;

        //Finally Add component since nothing is null
        Component cmpnt = obj.AddComponent(type);
        return cmpnt;
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
gameObject.AddComponentExt("YourScriptOrComponentName");
```

---

It is important to understand how I did it so that you can add support for new components in any future Unity updates.

**For any script created by users**:

**1**.Find out what needs to be in the *???* in the `Assembly.Load` function.

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.Load("???");
```

You can do that by putting this in your script:

```
Debug.Log("Info: " + this.GetType().Assembly);
```

I got: `Assembly-CSharp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null`

We should now replace *???* with that.

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.Load("Assembly-CSharp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null");
```

**2**.Find out what needs to be in the *???* in the `asm.GetType` function.

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.Load("Assembly-CSharp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null");
Type type = asm.GetType(???);
```

In this case, it is simply the name of the script you want to add to the GameObject.

Let's say that your script name is `NathanScript`:

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.Load("Assembly-CSharp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null");
Type type = asm.GetType("NathanScript"); 
gameObject.AddComponent(type);
```

---

**For Unity built in scripts/components scripts not created by users**:

Example of this is the `Rigidbody`, `Linerenderer`, `Image` components. Just any component not created by the user.

**1**.Find out what needs to be in the *???* in the `Assembly.Load` function.

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.Load("???");
```

You can do that by putting this in your script:

```
ParticleSystem pt = gameObject.AddComponent<ParticleSystem>();
Debug.Log("Info11: " + pt.GetType().Assembly);
```

I got: `UnityEngine, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null`

We should now replace *???* with that.

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.Load("UnityEngine, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null");
```

**2**.Find out what needs to be in the *???* in the `asm.GetType` function.

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.Load("UnityEngine, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null");
Type type = asm.GetType(???);
```

You can do that by putting this in your script:

```
ParticleSystem pt = gameObject.AddComponent<ParticleSystem>();
Debug.Log("Info: " + pt.GetType());
```

I got: `UnityEngine.ParticleSystem`

Remember that `ParticleSystem` is used as an example here. So the final string that will go to the `asm.GetType` function will be calculated like this:

```
string typeString = "UnityEngine." + componentName;
```

Let's say that the Component you want to add is [`LineRenderer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.html):

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.Load("UnityEngine, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null");
string typeString = "UnityEngine." + "LineRenderer";
Type type = asm.GetType(typeString); 
gameObject.AddComponent(type);
```

---

**Putting it together in an extension method**:

As you can see, adding scripts you created and the script/components that comes with Unity requires totally different process. You can fix this by checking if the type if `null`. If the type is `null`, perform the other step. If the other step is `null` too then the script simply does **not** exit.

Comment: Even though this method is fairly good it will fail when you would want to check for the type from your project within nested namespace let's say `Namespace1.Namespace2.ClassDefinition` which does not require much of an investigation : [http://rextester.com/KHVGJ63716](http://rextester.com/KHVGJ63716)

Comment: @m.rogalski `It is made like that by design`. When I was making that function, I asked my self "what happens when you have two classes with the-same name but in different namespace?" That's a conflict right there so all have to do is type in the *fully qualified name*. It will find it. So, `gameObject.AddComponentExt("Namespace1.Namespace2.ClassDefinition");` will work and it will find just that script.

Comment: @Programmer I did try using your extension method but it doesn't seem to be able to load the assembly, console shows: `FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'UnityEngine.Analytics, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`. It doesn't work with the extension or from manually loading the Assembly from `this.GetType().Assembly()`. Sorry for the delay on feedback, was (overwhelmingly) working on other things.
`

Comment: All you have to do is put the switch statement inside a try catch block. Check the updated code. Let me know if there is a problem.

Comment: @Programmer As a matter of coincidence I just did, keeps on not loading it and raising the `Failed to Add component` exception you made. On the catch it keeps raising `FileNotFoundException` with the `UnityEngine.Analytics` and `UnityEngine.HoloLens` Assemblies.

Comment: This code was tested with Unity 5.6 beta. You are probably using the lower version and therefore missing HoloLens and Analytics and other assemblies not enabled. This is why I commented out the `Debug.Log`.  *Don't uncomment it*. This code should work for any script or component. **If it does not, let me know**. Comment out the `Debug.Log` for the Exception like it is in my answer and everything should work fine.

Comment: Do a simple test with `gameObject.AddComponentExt("ParticleSystem");` and tell me if `ParticleSystem` is attached to your GameObject.

Comment: Yes, it did add a particle system, video player, mesh, audio, canvas... Any standard component I try out it works, everything except custom scripts (sorry about the delay, again...).

Comment: lol It took almost a month to get your reply. This works for me 100 percent with custom script. Can you create a new question with the custom script that's not working and also include the code from this answer. This post is already long. I will provide a new code that will AddComponent if I am 100 sure that you are not doing anything wrong.

Comment: Yes I'm sorry again, I got moved to work with animation controller (plus lectures, exams and essays), don't even know if I'll need this anymore lol, but anyway I would like to know what/why it isn't working as learning material. I can post a new question but the thing is no scripts work, even a empty monobehaviour class that does nothing.

Comment: Ahh midterms....I get it. Just create an empty script called `Test`. Create another one called `ComponentTest`. Now, put `gameObject.AddComponentExt("ComponentTest");` in the `Start()` function of the `Test` script. Attach the `Test` script to an empty GameObject. When you run it, `ComponentTest` script should be attached to that empty GameObject. Now, if this does not work then create a new question with this information and I will look into it. I am saying this because it works here.

Comment: Oh my, it did work, and that made me test something that makes me embarassed I didn't test before, I was using your class in an Editor script (in the editor folder), I moved to another script outside the Editor folder, the same one that has the parent class for everything I'm doing, and it just started working. Although I am relieved it is working now I'm not sure why... A class inside the Editor folder is unable to check for Assemblies outside the UnityEditor namespace (even though I was using UnityEngine)?

Comment: Really, don't know why it doesn't work while placed in the Editor folder. Maybe, that's a bug. Not sure but glad it works for you now.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing this like so :

```
if(GUILayout.Button("Attach script"))
{
    // check if type is contained in your assembly:
    Type type = typeof(MeAssemblyType).Assembly.GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == scriptname);
    if(type != null)
    {
        // script exists in the same assembly that MeAssemblyType is
        obj.AddComponent(type); // add the component
    }
    else
    { 
        // display some error message
    }
}
```

Of course this will fail if you use some plugins ( dependencies ) which contains other components but to deal with this you can just check dependencies of your assembly :

```
typeof(MeAssemblyType) // your type from Assembly-CSharp 
    .Assembly // Assembly-CSharp assembly
    .GetReferencedAssemblies() // get referenced assemblies
    .FirstOrDefault(m => 
        m.Assembly // from this assembly
        .GetTypes() // get all types
        .FirstOrDefault(t => 
            t.Name == scriptname // select first one that matches the name
        )
    )
```

**Remarks :**

`GetReferencedAssemblies` method will only return assemblies that were "used" ( loaded ) by your assembly. To make it a bit clear, assume you're referencing these assemblies:

1. System.Xml,
2. NewtonsoftJson

And this piece of code :

```
static void Main()
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(<some_xml_input>);
}
```

Then the output of `GetReferencedAssemblies` will look somewhat like that :

```
>>> System.Xml, Version=<version>, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=<key>
```

Meaning it will not load `NewtonsoftJson` because it was not used inside of that assembly.

**Better suggestion :**

I would suggest you mixing up the method from [@Programmer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42357931/3179310) answer but not load the assemblies because they are already loaded when Unity's editor starts with your project. Instead use `GetReferencedAssemblies` method and from there you should call `GetTypes` method to retrieve all possible types in that assembly. ( It will be slow but will guarantee you the desired results ) After that you can just use `FirstOrDefault` or just iterate through the `Type[]` yourself to find the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is still possible. Use this

```
UnityEngineInternal.APIUpdaterRuntimeServices.AddComponent(GameObject go, "", string componentName);
```

Hope that helps

Comment: This is deprecated as well as `"AddComponent(string)`.

Comment: Deprecated means it will be removed very soon. It uses `AddComponent(string)` under the hood.

Comment: Question is regarding current Unity version not future ones. This solution does work currently with Unity 5.5

Comment: It says deprecated on my side. So, you are encouraging OP to use a deprecated API? This simply does not solve the problem.

Comment: Guess you haven't tried if this actually work? @Programmer

Comment: @Programmer any other idea how approach the actual issue here?

Comment: Last time I tired to do this, I failed miserably because every API I found was deprecated. I will try experiment on this again and let you know but it's not a good idea to use provided deprecated stuff in an answer.

Comment: You can check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Decompile AddComponentWindow of Unity. Also added the link:
[AddComponentAdjusted](https://github.com/winalex/AddComponentUnity/wiki)

Then call the window something like this:

```
  ws.winx.editor.windows.AddComponentWindow.Show(rect);

            ws.winx.editor.windows.AddComponentWindow.OnClose += OnCloseComponentSelectedFromPopUpMenu;
            ws.winx.editor.windows.AddComponentWindow.ComponentSelected += (menuPath) => ComponentSelectedFromPopUpMenu(positionData.Item1, menuPath);
```

Handle return

```
    private void ComponentSelectedFromPopUpMenu(Vector2 position, string menuPath) {
        
        
                    MonoScript monoScript;
        
                    char[] kPathSepChars = new char[]
                    {
                        '/',
                        '\\'
                    };
        
                    menuPath = menuPath.Replace(" ", "");
                    string[] pathElements = menuPath.Split(kPathSepChars);
        
                    string fileName = pathElements[pathElements.Length - 1].Replace(".cs", "");
        
        
        
        
                    if (pathElements[0] == "Assets") {
        
                        Debug.LogWarning("Unity need to compile new added file so can be included");
        
        
                    } else if (pathElements.Length == 2) {
        
//use fileName
                        //do something
        
                        
                    } else if (pathElements[1] == "Scripts") {//Component/Scripts/MyScript.cs
                        
        
                        string[] guids = AssetDatabase.FindAssets("t:Script " + fileName.Replace(".cs", ""));
        
                        if (guids.Length > 0) {
        
                            for (int i = 0; i < guids.Length; i++) {
                                monoScript = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath(AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath(guids[i]), typeof(MonoScript)) as MonoScript;
                                Type typet = monoScript.GetClass();
        
                                if (typet == null) continue;
        
        
                               
        
                    } else {//Component/Physics/Rigidbody
                        //try to find by type, cos probably Unity type
                        Type unityType = ReflectionUtility.GetType("UnityEngine." + fileName);
        
                        if (unityType != null) {
        
    //do something
        
                            return;
        
                        }
        
        
        
        
        
        //Based on attribute  [AddComponentMenu("Logic/MyComponent")] 
                        //Component/Logics/MyComponent
                        string[] guids = AssetDatabase.FindAssets("t:Script " + fileName.Replace(".cs", ""));
        
                        if (guids.Length > 0) {
        
                            for (int i = 0; i < guids.Length; i++) {
                                monoScript = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath(AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath(guids[i]), typeof(MonoScript)) as MonoScript;
                                Type typet = monoScript.GetClass();
        
                                if (typet == null) continue;
        
                                object[] addComponentMenuAttributes = typet.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AddComponentMenu), true);
        
        
        
                                if (addComponentMenuAttributes != null && addComponentMenuAttributes.Length > 0 && "Component/" + ((AddComponentMenu)addComponentMenuAttributes[0]).componentMenu == menuPath)
                                {
        
                                    //do somethings
        
                                }
                            }
        
        
                        }
        
        
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the assemblies in the app domain.
Then search for that name in that assembly's GetTypes() (like [@mrogal.ski](https://mrogal.ski/)'s answer)

```
static Type FindType(string typeName, string namespaceString = "") 
{
    foreach(var asm in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()) 
    {
        var type = asm.GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(t => 
            t.Name == typeName && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(namespaceString) || namespaceString == t.Namespace));

        if (type != null) { return type; }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Usage like this:

```
var someGameObject = new GameObject("FindTypeDemoObject");
var rbType = FindType("Rigidbody");
someGameObject.AddComponent(rbType);

var someMonoBType = FindType("SomeMonoB", "Fake.Example.Namespace");
someGameObject.AddComponent(someMonoBType);
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me `obj.AddComponent(System.Type.GetType(ScriptToAdd.name + ",Assembly-CSharp"));`

- ScriptToAdd is UnityEngine.Object