# Does Unity call Start() when OnApplicationPause(true)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, onpause

When receiving an incoming call for example, `OnApplicationPause(false)` is called, and when returning back to the app `OnApplicationPause(true)` is called. What's going to happen when returning? Do all my gameobjects on the scene run Start() again?  If so that's bad because it'll reset everything to default in my case. I read different answers on different sites, I wonder why it's not clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `Start()` will not be called again after `OnApplicationPause(true)`.

> Start is called on the frame when a script is enabled just before any
>   of the Update methods are called the first time.
>
> Like the Awake function, Start is called exactly once in the lifetime
>   of the script.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html

Comment: So what am I going to "lose" when `OnApplicationPause` is `true` again?  If `Start()` isn't being called, would all my gamebjects keep their attached scripts preferences (variables) ? And their Transform position exactly like before pausing? Why do people serialize on `OnApplicationPause` if `Start()` isn't being called again.

Comment: Not sure why you would "lose" anything. Your objects wouldnt looses any value or change positions just because OnApplicationPause() is called. People use OnApplicationPause() to know when the appliation gets paused.

Comment: I meant to say that from what I understand- when a game pauses, we should serialize variables so we don't lose them when resuming (still not sure what exactly can get lost). Like that answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45847057/do-i-have-to-use-onpause-onstart-ondestroy

Comment: To visualize this answer scroll down to scheme https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html