# Unity - passing script by reference from editor, instantiating it on object at runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**So basically I want to end with several ingame objects, each having few .cs scripts with monobehaviour. (different set of scripts on each object)**

*party of characters with their skills*

**Those scripts on each character can vary over time**

*characters learning new skills/abandoning old*

**So when the game starts, I want to attach the scripts to objects dynamically at runtime**

*based on player decision in skill tree*

**Is there any way how can I do this without using reflection?**

**EDIT: It seems I found solution how to make it work without reflection**

```
public class TestSkill : MonoBehaviour {}

public class TestFireball : TestSkill {}
public class TestMeleeAttack : TestSkill {}

public class TestSkillBook : MonoBehaviour {

    public MonoScript script;

    void Start () {

        System.Type t = script.GetClass();

        TestSkill skill = gameObject.AddComponent(t) as TestSkill;

    }

}
```

Comment: I'm finding it hard to understand your question. Could you please try to rewrite it more clearly? (The bold and italics aren't helping make anything clearer at the moment, either.)

Comment: The problem is on my side, I am not very good at explaining :) Basically, I want to dynamically attach scripts to object, but I dont know beforehand which scripts I will attach.

Comment: Do you understand now or should I clarify more?

Comment: Not really, I'm afraid. Giving a concrete example with code would help a lot.

Comment: My code have thousands of lines. But I will try from different angle. I know how to create a class with gameobject variable, put it on prefab, fill the variable in unity editor and then pass it to another script runtime. I would like to do the same with script type.

Comment: Your real code may have thousands of lines - but that doesn't mean you need thousands of lines of code to write a demonstration of what you're trying to achieve. It's also worth bearing in mind that there are lots of C# developers who use Stack Overflow but don't have any/much Unity experience, but may still be able to help you with enough context.

Comment: That might be the thing. Half of my problem is connected to editor itself. I am basically trying to solve how to pass certain type of information from unity editor to runtime code and back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to attach the scripts to objects dynamically at run-time.

he [`AddComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html) function is used to attach scripts to GameObjects.

Your Object

```
public GameObject yourgameObject;
```

Attach script to it:

```
yourgameObject.AddComponent<YourScript>();
```

**EDIT:**

> The problem is, I dont know if it will be MyScript1 or MyScript2. I
>   dont want it to be hardcoded, but modifiable via editor/ingame UI.

I think that you are looking for `AddComponent` that can take `string` as param.
There used to be one like [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html):

```
public Component AddComponent(string className);
```

but it was deprecated years ago. I made a new one called `AddComponentExt` as extension method last year and you can get it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42357931/3785314). It can be used like this:

```
yourgameObject.AddComponentExt<"YourScript">();
```

You can add script even if it doesn't exist yet. You will get run-time error instead of compile-time error in that case.

> Is there any way how can I do this without using reflection?

**No**, you can't do this without reflection since it doesn't exist yet. That's what reflection is used for.

Comment: Yes, but how do I get reference to MyScript?

Comment: Let's say your script is called or named `YourScript`, you attach it to your GameObject with `yourgameObject.AddComponent<YourScript>();`. Which part is confusing to you?

Comment: The problem is, I dont know if it will be MyScript1 or MyScript2. I dont want it to be hardcoded, but modifiable via editor/ingame UI.

Comment: And I havent found a way how to pass it like other variable types

Comment: Thank you for extension method. Just tu clarify: Why is it possible to pass a variable from editor through gameobject with some class to runtime, but I cant so the same with script? Like passing it through something like MonobehaviorScript variable?

Comment: You are welcome. *"Why is it possible to pass a variable from editor through gameobject with some class to runtime, but I cant so the same with script?"* I don't understand that question. Can you rephrase it and give an example?

Comment: Lets say you have class A{ GameObject a}. When this class is on object in scene, I can assign the variable via editor, press play and then use the infromation in runtime. I would like to have class B{ MonobehaviourScript b }, assign MyScript1 in editor to variable b, press play and then use SomeObject.AddComponent<typeof(instanceB.b)>();

Comment: Because yes, I dont know the type of class beforehand, but I know that it is derived from MonoBehaviour and as such can be attached to objects, should that be sufficient?

Comment: To use `typeof`, it has to be `typeof(YourScriptName)` not type of a variable type of that script. For example `yourgameObject.AddComponent(typeof(YourScript));` and `YourScript` must be the name of the script. That's how to use`typeof`. Although, I don't think that will be helpful to you. You need to use the `string` version with the extension in my answer,

Comment: Ah, sorry, not very skilled in c#...meant something like yourgameObject.AddComponent(instanceB.b.GetType()); probably

Comment: @Colp Point for the inspector/script part is, that, since you declare the member variable, it knows what to expect when you drop somethiing into the slot in the inspector. That is of course different for what you want since there is nothing declared.

Comment: Again, this is C# syntax because it takes `Type` as param. It has to be `yourgameObject.AddComponent(typeof(YourScript))`. If you want to use something like `instanceB.b.GetType()` then you still need m extension.  In that case, it would be `yourgameObject.AddComponentExt(instanceB.b.GetType().FullName)`.

Comment: @GunnarB. But there is. Cant you declare it as Monobehaviour type? Since its derived from it.

Comment: I might found a solution. The class is called MonoScript and has method GetClass...

Comment: @Colp `GetClass` does pretty much the same as `GetType` I think. Point is that MonoScript will not know the stuff you have in your custom scripts. Now, to actually get to now this, you'd need reflection again (or a cast, but this would basically require hardcoding everything on compile time).

Comment: @Colp I added some example on what you'd have to do (using reflection).

Comment: @Programmer Your answer is no longer correct, see edit of my OP.

Comment: @Colp Sorry but my answer is still correct. It looks like you think of this as a magic. It's not. It's either a compile-time or a run-time. Compile time is when you use the `typeof`. Run-time is when you use anything to get the  `Type` an this is reflection.Your `script.GetClass()` returns `Type` and is using reflection to do so. So your edit is wrong. Now, let's talk about `MonoScript` which is another issue. The `MonoScript` is from the `UnityEditor` namespace which means that it can only be used in the Editor. You will not be able to use it in a build. It won't even compile. Hope you get it

Comment: Okay, thanks, I think I understand it now. My skills with C# are still very limited.

Answer (score 0):

Since this doesn't fit into the comments of Programmers answer, some example and to clarify on what you can/must do:

```
// The component to add
public class B : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void TestCall()
    {
        Debug.Log("Success");
    }
}




public class A : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string ToAddName = "B";

    private void Start()
    {
        System.Type t = System.Type.GetType(ToAddName);
        AddComponent(t);    // This does successfully add the component (assuming it exists)

        Debug.Log(t.GetType());    // This will give out "System.MonoType"

        // This doesn't work since it is not known that this is actually "B", not "MonoScript"
        GetComponent(t).TestCall();

        // What is possible is this, requires hardcoding the method name though:
        System.Reflection.MethodInfo mI = t.GetMethod("TestCall");
        var c = GetComponent(t);
        mI.Invoke(c, null);    // null because "TestCall" doesn't take params
    }
}
```

This is not meant to be an actual solution, I'd rather say that there is probably a (better) way to set up your whole construct so that you don't have this problem at all.

Comment: Works for custom classes but won't work with built-in ones like AudioSource. `string ToAddName = "AudioSource";` will fail

Comment: @PerformanceFreak This wasn't meant to be an actual answer, but some example code refering to the comments of Programmers answer, should have wrote that. Otherwise OP seemingly only wants to add his custom components (or at least those are the problematic ones).

Comment: @GunnarB. It seems I found solution that doesnt need reflection. Check my edit.

Comment: @Colp That is a solution I mentioned in the comments of Programmers answer: casting.